# Can't get all the local storage data and put it into separate divs

Tags: javascript, html

I ran into a problem and I can't figure it out. I try to retrieve data from local storage and set local_storage_key as the attribute's value and local_storage_value as innerHTML for the div.

I have three items stored in local storage, however, for some reason only one element is created (i.e. one div with the attribute that equals local_storage_key and it's innerHTML set to local_storage_value).

How can I get all three elements retrieved and exposed in HTML?

Here is my code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    let key = localStorage.key(i);
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    newDiv.classList.add("task");
    newDiv.setAttribute("task-id", key);
    newDiv.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(key);
    form.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newDiv);
  }
```

Here is the code that saves data from the input into the local_storage.

```
function createTask() {
  submit.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // needed to prevent page from refresh upon click on submit

    let data = input.value;

    if (data === "") {
      return; // check-up to forbid passing an emty value
    } else {
      let newTask = document.createElement("div");
      newTask.classList.add("task");
      newTask.textContent = data;
      form.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newTask);
      input.value = "";

      function generateRandomInteger(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
      }

      let storageId = generateRandomInteger(20);
      let storageValue = data;

      newTask.setAttribute("task-id", storageId);
      localStorage.setItem(storageId, storageValue);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me:
https://jsfiddle.net/srxoL4ma/3/

Comment: Share code where you set items to localStorage.

Comment: @vanowm (or anyone) In your fiddle, do you know why the items are added to the page and printed in the order 0, 2, 1?

Comment: @wazz I've noticed that too...it seems `localStorage` does not retain the order items were set. https://jsfiddle.net/0rxhw213/ What's interesting, when I added another item named "zoom" it was always first in the list and all others were in reverse sequence they were set.

Comment: @NavnathJadhav I edited the initial question and added the code that saves the data into local storage. Please take a look. Hope it helps